# How to make a very clean and sleek frosted gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I am new to graphic design and photoshop. I found this app called Gear Rise by Nanovation on the App Store and was wondering if anyone knew how to create the frosted-like gradient in the background? I don't really know how that designer got those different colors in there and how it has a frosted look on top, it looks very clean and sleek and I would like to know how to achieve that look!

[image]

Comment: I don't know why you think it looks frosted

Comment: looks like a simple gradient or gradient mesh to me, just a little trial and error and you can probably get there. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Terminology comes as you learn this stuff.

What you are seeing is a gradient blend. If you have access to Adobe Illustrator, I would suggest looking into learning the **Gradient Mesh Tool**

This allows you to make complex multi-colored gradients that can follow shape of the artwork.

As always I would recommend you look for some image reference to build a swatches for the colors your would like.

Here's a decent tutorial to get you started.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8LEKLzRhN0